# UIAutomation Scripts examples

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, instruments, ios-ui-automation

Does anyone found any examples on UIAutomation test scripts with sample projects? 
So far I found only WWDC2010 video covering the topic, but no sample scripts/projects to play around with.

Also is there any way to achieve code suggestions/auto-completion when editing scripts in Xcode/Instruments?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you're tied to it UIAutomation, but I greatly prefer KIF https://github.com/square/KIF from the fine folks over at Square. It has examples, and it fairly actively maintained.